# How can I find the first items in a list with a different value for a property using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an ordered list of objects, and I would like to find the index of each item where a property changes, and get a dictionary/list of pairs matching index to property. For example, finding the index of each new first letter in a list of words ordered alphabetically.

I can do this with a foreach loop:

```
Initials = new Dictionary<char, int>();
int i = 0;
foreach (var word in alphabeticallyOrderedList))
{
    if (!Initials.ContainsKey(word.First()))
    {
        Initials[word.First()] = i;
    }
    i++;
}
```

But I feel like there should be an elegant way of doing this with Linq.

Comment: Why? it works, doing it using LINQ adds no benefit

Comment: @Liam I agree when looking at functionality, but I find that LINQ is a lot more readable and makes my code a lot cleaner.

Comment: @RandomStranger: not always, especially when indexes are important. You also lose some debugging, exception handling and logging capabilities if you use a large LINQ query.

Comment: Yes I understand that, I'm not saying it would fit in this scenario. I'm just saying that *I find* that it makes my code more readable in *general*.

Comment: One idea would be to `GroupBy` by the letter!

Comment: Here I've given a quite simple example of a list of strings. But my actual list is taken from a database via EntityFramework, and has several processing steps before this using Linq; and that's not even considering future scenarios with extra Linq steps afterwards. And Linq does clever SQL optimisation, which I don't know enough to duplicate.

Comment: How would GroupBy give me the index? Thanks.

Comment: @Ollyver You state in the question that you have a list of objects, but now you're saying that the data source is an `IQueryable` that represents a DB query?  That's *completely* different and *radically* changes possible answers to the question (among other things, it means that your solution doesn't actually result in querying the database, when it's apparently(?) supposed to be).

Comment: I'm not trying to get people to solve my specific problem. I'm trying to find out if there is a well-known combination of a few Linq functions that does what my question above states. Since apparently, using Linq instead of foreach is controversial, I thought I'd better justify why it occurred to me as a question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have the same functionality with LINQ by using the overload of `Select` that exposes the index and by using `GroupBy` + `ToDictionary`:

```
 Initials = alphabeticallyOrderedList
    .Select((word, index) => new { Word = word, WordIndex = index })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Word[0])
    .ToDictionary(charGroup => charGroup.Key, charGroup => charGroup.First().WordIndex);
```

But to quote myself:

LINQ is not always more readable, especially when indexes are important. You also lose some debugging, exception handling and logging capabilities if you use a large LINQ query

Comment: Thanks, those are the functions that I was playing with but not managing to combine correctly!

Comment: agreed. This answers the question, but the foreach loop is more readable, debuggable, and quite possibly more performant. The only thing I'd do to clean up the OP's code is use a `for` loop and increment the `i` variable there.

Comment: I did not know you could use `.Select` to automatically get an index. Good to know.

Comment: @Carson: the only LINQ-methods that provide it are `Select` and `Where`. If you need them in other methods you have to use an anonymous type like i did. But remember that those indexes always refer to what you've projected previously. If i'd add `Select((g, index) => ...` after the `GroupBy` i'd get the indexes of the groups.